# React - Redux: Array in the store is not being updated correctly

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, redux

first sorry for my english, i'm a french dev, i start with react redux lib, i want to code form generator and i have problem to render an array. i explain me whit a code picture.
(i precise, for moment it's static)

i want to add question in a questions array : questions: [] construct like

```js
    questions : [
      {
        dataid: 1,
        label:"coucou",
        input: [
        {
          dataid: 1,
          type:"radio",
          value:"oui",
        },
        {
          dataid: 2,
          type:"radio",
          value:"non",
        }
      ]
           
      },
    ],
```

the code to add a question:

```js
   case ADD_OTHER_OPTION: {

          // je recherche le nombre d'option dans une question 
          let questionsInputLength = state.questions.map((items) => {
            return (items.input.length);
          } )

          // initialisation d'un dataid pour faire mon calcul et le rendre unique
          let idMax;
          if (state.questions.length > 0) {
           // si j'ai supprimé toute les options d'une question, j'ai encore la question de présente
           // et le [] input est à 0 donc je réinitialise le data id de la premier option à 0 
            if ((questionsInputLength.includes(0))) {
              idMax = ['0'];
            }
            else {
              // si j'ai déjà des options dans une question 
             state.questions.map((item) => {
                idMax = item.input.map((inputs) => inputs.dataid)
                return idMax;
              });            
            }
          }
          else {
            // si je n'ai pas encore de question, 
            // j'initie un dataid à 0 sous forme de []pour la fonction Math.max() +1
            idMax = ['0'];
          }
          
          const hightId = Math.max(...idMax) + 1;
          // initialisation d'une nouvelle option
          let newOption;
          // si j'ai le meme data id dans le state et dans l'action et que mon [] de questions est sup à 0
          if (state.dataid == action.dataid && state.questions.length > 0) {
          
            console.log('je suis dans le if du add option');
          
            newOption = state.questions.map((question) => {
              
              if (question.dataid == action.dataid) {
                console.log('meme id' + '  ' + question.dataid + '  '+ action.dataid)
          
                const newInput = {
                  dataid: hightId,
                  type: action.value,
                  value: state.inputSelectedOptionValue,
                };
          
                return {
                  ...question,
                  dataid: action.dataid,
                  label: state.inputQuizQuestionValue,
                  input: [ ...question.input, newInput]
                  
                };
              } 
              else {
                console.log('pas le meme dataid, autre question')
                // TODO revoir tout ce code, j'ecrase la question au lieu de la rajouter et du coup je rajotue les autre input sous la  premiere question.
                  
                  const newQuestion = {
                    // ...question,
                    dataid: state.dataid,
                    label: state.inputQuizQuestionValue,
                    input: 
                    [
                      {
                        dataid: hightId,
                        type: action.value,
                        value: state.inputSelectedOptionValue,
                      },
                    ]
                  }
            
                  return newQuestion

              }
          
            })
            
            console.log('je vais return avant le else du add option');
            console.log(newOption);
            return {
              ...state,
              questions: [...newOption],
              inputSelectedOptionValue: '',
            }
          }
          // si mon tableau de question est vide
          else {
            console.log('je suis dans le else du add option');
          
            newOption = {
              dataid: state.dataid,
              label: state.inputQuizQuestionValue,
              input: 
              [
                {
                  dataid: hightId,
                  type: action.value,
                  value: state.inputSelectedOptionValue,
                },
              ]
            }
          }
          console.log('dernier return  du add option');
          
          return {
            ...state,
            questions: [...state.questions, newOption],
            inputSelectedOptionValue: '',
          }
        }
```

when i don't have question in my array the code is ok, i can add one.
when i have one i can add multi input whit the same type and other valu and other dataId.
But when i want to add a other question, the code is not ok, i crush questions to add an other, it's normal, the " return newQuestion" put the question in "newOption" and this return

```js
 return {
              ...state,
              questions: [...newOption],
              inputSelectedOptionValue: '',
            }
```

crush all questions..
BUT, if i change this return for "questions: [...state.questions, newOption] " don't working when i want to add an other input in a question..
i try to change the "return newQuestion", i try a lot of thing but nothing is good.. i loose my hair

I hope u find courage to read..

thank a lot.. and "Passez une bonne journée les devs"

Thery

[console.log(state.questions) after adding one question whith other input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2O2b.png)

[When i add question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHaMt.png)

Comment: Point of clarity: instead of declaring `newOption` in an outer scope and then using it for two completely different purposes (an array and a single value), declare it in the inner scopes, and use `const` if if doesn't change after the declaration, and if it's an array make it plural `newOptions`.

Comment: If `newOption` is indeed an array you should be spreading it also, i.e. `questions: [...state.questions, ...newOption]` but your code is really hard to follow and you should really post the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Other feedback: use back ticks to format any code inline in your text and don't post links to images that could be inline images or better still actual formatted text using makdown code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases in your `reducer`, 1. adding a new question to the `questions` array, 2. adding a new `option` to the current question.

Your implementation for adding a question would look like this:

```
return {
  ...state,
  questions: [...state.questions, newQuestion],
  inputSelectedOptionValue: '',
}
```

But for adding new options to the current question, you need to know the question id for which you want to add an option.

Assume that we need to update question id 2 to add a new option to it.

There are two parts, first need to find that question and after that, add a new option to this founded question.

```
return {
  ..state,
  questions: state.questions.map(question => 
    (question.id === 2 ?
       {...question, input: [...question.input, newOption]} 
       : question)
    )
}
```

**Note:** with assuming that target question id is 2, we found that and add the new option to the `input` array. but you must replace the **hardcoded** question id **2** with your `questionId` which you want to add a new option to it.